# How to move entire row based on text in a single cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching on the internet where to find the most efficient and simple way of the following:

I have a spreadsheet that contains 3 sheets:

1. information
2. training
3. Leavers

Within the information sheet, column B contains a validation text that is conditionally formatted. There are two validation options:

1. Active
2. Leaver

I want that once the cell value is changed from 'active' to 'Leaver' that the whole row would be removed from the sheet and moved to 'Leaver's sheet.

I have used the code below, it works, however if there is no Leavers it will transfer the first row of 'active'. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

```
Sub AlexR688(x)
    'For http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-q...ific-text.html
    'Using autofilter to Copy rows that contain centain text to a sheet called Errors
    Dim LR As Long

    Range("B2").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    LR = Sheets("Personal Information").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    LR1 = Sheets("Leavers").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Sheets("Personal Informaiton").Range("B2:C" & LR)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Leaver", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=":Leaver"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Leavers").Range("A" & LR1)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Secondly, I want to make the same in the  'Training' sheet. But in there, column B, contains the same 'Active', 'Leavers' which is referenced from personal information. So, once the Personal information sheet column B is changed from 'active' to 'leaver', training sheet will change as well, but i want the row in the training sheet would be deleted.

Thirdly, if I accidentally moved row from Personal information sheet to Leavers sheet, is it possible that by selecting back to 'active' cell value the row would move back to where it was?

Thank you very much. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: When and what triggers the sub you use? Do you have a button or something?

Comment: I have created a button, because I do not know how to automate it. If the cell value is changed from 'active' to 'leaver'

Comment: vba is an event driven language. In order to automate something by running some code, you need an event to happen. Here, you do not have a form control, in order for an event to trigger. So, you will need a combobox or something and use one of it's properties (like on change property) to trigger your function. Otherwise, what you want cannot happen!

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way

```
  Private Sub imperecheaza_Click()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim Rand As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")    
   Rand = 3
     Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value <> "" And Rand < 65000
       If ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = gksluri.Value * 1 And ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value = gksluri.List(gksluri.ListIndex, 1) * 1 Then
         ws.Rows(Rand) = ""    '(here you will delete entire Row)
         gksluri.RemoveItem gksluri.ListIndex
         Exit Do
         End If
       Rand = Rand + 1
    Loop
  End Sub
```